# React/Node/Mongoose saving time on requests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, performance, mongoose, pagespeed

**component I'm making:**
I'm making a booking component with a modal. It has a timesheet and options to choose various locations. every time user changes the location, another timesheet is fetched for each location.

**network flow of the page:**

1. **download location:** it fetches for all locations customers can choose from in the db and stores locations state. (this takes about 900ms).
2. **then download timesheet:** once locations is set, it selects a default location information then fetches other requests to download 7 days worth of timesheets. (this takes another 900ms, but only 6 async calls are made at a time. the last one is executive after some delay. in total the whole fetch takes about 1800ms). this piece executes after locations update using
   `useEffect(()=>{ //some code// }, [locations])`
3. page loads up

**problem**
evidently, this is too slow. the whole thing takes about 2.5 seconds to 3 seconds to load. i am thinking about ways to improve the time it takes for the page to load.

**solutions I was thinking**
I could just start downloading all the timesheet data before location data is downloaded. I think I can store the default location information somewhere in the site.

**option 1)** I think I can store default location data in the redux (stored in user schema and gets updated to redux when a user logs in so that it can be used when timesheet component needs to load without having to wait for location data to be downloaded). the problem is i'm now replicating the same location data within the db. maybe it's not a problem, but my OCD wants to do without replicating anything.

**option 2)** I can get rid of the user specific default data. I think I can just store sth like `var defaultLocation = {  id: // objectId of a location//  }` in the component code itself but i'm losing the user specificity, which would be a very nice feature to have.

**option 3)** ??? I feel like I'm facing a trade off here, but I'm hoping if there would be any other solutions. Any tips and helps would be much appreciated!

Comment: A solution can be implementing db cache for fetching from DB. (```cachegoose``` and ```redis``` for mongodb). And also you can aggregate both downloading locations and timesheets and fetch once using REST, Also you can use ```graphQL``` if there is more scenarios like this.

Comment: @cybercoder Thanks. I think caching might be a good solution. I will look into that. About location calls, I didn't aggregate it as you suggested. Changes in location data is unlikely to occur frequently (about once a year, if that). So I just created a JSON file and compiled it with the entire front end.